# Sum up random but not defined numbers

Tags: python, class, random

I am trying to find a way to add up just the randomly generated numbers, but not the defined numbers from my code given below.

```
import random
class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, species, age, tricks, fleas=None):
        if fleas is None:
            fleas = random.randint(0,10)
        self.name = name
        self.species = species
        self.age = age
        self.tricks = tricks
        self.fleas = fleas
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} is {self.age} year old {self.species} who can {self.tricks} with {self.fleas} fleas"

Snaps = Pet("Snaps", "Dog", 8, "fetch and roll over")
Charlie = Pet("Charlie", "Cat", 6, "roll over and play dead")
Pabu = Pet("Pabu", "Ferret", 4, "shake hands and open jars")

print(Snaps)
print(Charlie)
print(Pabu)
def randnums():
    total=0
    for count in range(0,10):
        number = random.randint(0,10)
        total+=number
    print(total)

randnums()
```

Right now it seems to be adding up all the numbers, but I just need the total number of randomly generated fleas.
Also, is there a way to make the fleas a class attribute while still making them a random number and showing up in the print?
Thanks!

Comment: Your `randnums` function is just adding 10 random numbers.  It does nothing with your Pet collection.  What did you want here?

Comment: I wanted it to add up the randomly generated values of the fleas, you other answer helped a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the number of fleas, just access the fleas member variable.
For instance, `Charlie.fleas` will return the number of fleas which was generated when Charlie was created.

You've created an entirely unrelated function which adds up 10 random numbers, so that is naturally what you're getting.

Tip: Name the variables exactly what they are. Calling this `number_of_fleas` (or similar) would be a lot less confusing, especially when you're just starting out.

Comment: print("Total fleas in household",Snaps.fleas + Charlie.fleas + Pabu.fleas)

This worked for me, thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

Fleas is already a member variable.

```
import random
class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, species, age, tricks, fleas=None):
        if fleas is None:
            fleas = random.randint(0,10)
        self.name = name
        self.species = species
        self.age = age
        self.tricks = tricks
        self.fleas = fleas
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} is {self.age} year old {self.species} who can {self.tricks} with {self.fleas} fleas"

pets = [
    Pet("Snaps", "Dog", 8, "fetch and roll over"),
    Pet("Charlie", "Cat", 6, "roll over and play dead"),
    Pet("Pabu", "Ferret", 4, "shake hands and open jars")
]

for pet in pets:
    print(pet)

fleas = sum(pet.fleas for pet in pets)
print( f"There are {fleas} total fleas." )
```

Comment: They way you organized the pets so they can be printed all at one time was going to be my next question, thanks for showing me that!

Comment: Now When I try to print just one pet using your code with
print(Pabu) it doesn't work. Do I have to use a different command?

Comment: In that case, you'd say `pets[2]`.  If you want to refer to them by name, you could change `pets` to a dictionary, with the pet name as a key.  That would change the `for` loops slightly (`for pet in pets.values()`), but would allow you to write `pets['Pabu']`.